# hierarchic networks: sub-network within higher level node?

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

in vis.js-network, is there a way to render a (smaller) network within a node?

e.g., a hierarchic network where the node of the top level in the hierarchy acts as a container for another set of nodes (from a lower hierarchy level)?

Answer (score 0):

I did not manage to find an interactive solution with vis.js.
however, hierarchic nodes are natively supported by http://js.cytoscape.org - so I switched to this javascript library.

the only native (vis.js) work-around that I found was via custom svg rendering within a node. then, however the lower hierarchy levels would not be interactive anymore.

sample generated with js.cytoscape (layout is manually adujsted):
[image: sample generated with js.cytoscape (layout is manually adujsted)]